# Google AutoML - detect form fields on an image

Tags: google-vision, vision

Is there a way to get coordinates from an form field on an image (scanned image), by using Google vision?

- With the (LocalizedObjectAnnotation) can Google detect only objects and creatures
- Google OCR (fullTextAnnotation) detects only text

Scenario:

I got an scanned formular. From this scan i would get all form field-positions (input-fields).

It don't work with one or both google method's "LocalizedObjectAnnotation" and "fullTextAnnotation". Because one detect only objects / creatures and the other one only text. So both can't find the input-field in the image.

Has anyone an idee how i get the coordinates for the input-fields?